# Pinescript: Referencing another security in an indicator

Tags: pine-script, trading, indicator

I'm attempting to make an indicator that references a moving average of a different security.

For example: Change the color of candles on "ETHUSD" chart if "BTCUSD" price is above the 200 day weekly moving average.

I haven't found a way to reference the data of a moving average on a different security or symbol. I'm not sure if this is even possible within Pinescript of Tradingview.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible. Use something like:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
priceIsAboveMa = close > sma(close, 200)
btcPriceIsAboveMa = security("BITSTAMP:BTCUSD", "D", priceIsAboveMa)
barcolor(btcPriceIsAboveMa ? color.lime : color.red)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the assistance.